# How to save the content of the BrowserWindow into image?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am building an Electron App and I would like to save the content of the current window into an image using Electron just like those One-click full page screen captures in Google Chrome.

What is the best approach to accomplish this?

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
win.capturePage([rect, ]callback)
```

- `rect` Rectangle (optional), the bounds to capture
- `callback` Function which return an `image` (NativeImage)

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#wincapturepagerect-callback